# Google Admin SDK Directory API limits

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am constructing an app that will query the Google Admin SDK/Directory API and retrieve users group information.  This is the only type of query that will be performed.  Will these queries count towards the allotted 150,000 Directory API queries per day for my project? This app could potentially be running this type of query against 100's of customers, each with their own directory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All API calls count against the API quota. If you find your app is approaching the 150k daily limit, you can request your limit be raised. In my experience, Google is willing to raise the quota as long as you have a valid use case.